# No clue what simple thing I am overlooking for this mysql query

Tags: mysql, math

[image]So I thought instead of writing a whole bunch of php and doing a second mysql call lets just modify the ordinal table by doing the math IN the MySql call.

```
> SELECT wp_castle_rss.`building_level`,
>        SUM ((wp_castle_rss.'building_food' *.2)-12000000 )AS wp_castle_rss.'building_food' ,
>        wp_castle_rss.`building_wood`,
>        wp_castle_rss.`building_iron`,
>        wp_castle_rss.`building_silver`, CASE
>     WHEN wp_castle_rss.'building_food' <0  THEN wp_castle_rss.'building_food'=0 END FROM wp_castle_rss
```

No clue why that is giving me an error.   I need after the math if its zero to just feed the table being created a ZEro cause the table software isn't smart enough to ask me if negatives are bad for display purpose.

```
SELECT wp_castle_rss.`building_level`,
      ((wp_castle_rss.`building_food` *.2)-12000000 )AS `building_food` ,
       wp_castle_rss.`building_wood`,
       wp_castle_rss.`building_iron`,
       wp_castle_rss.`building_silver`,
CASE
    WHEN `building_food` <0  THEN `building_food`=0
END
FROM wp_castle_rss
```

Comment: What is the error? And why is `building_food` wrapped within apostrophes instead of backquotes?

Comment: Does the error look something like this? `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''building_food' *.2)-12000000 )`

Comment: The simple thing you're overlooking is normalisation. A database table is not a spreadsheet

Comment: cannot calculate position of ((wp_castle_rss.`building_food` *.2)-12000000 ) within , ((wp_castle_rss.`building_food` *.2)-12000000 )AS `building_food` , wp_castle_rss.`building_wood`, wp_castle_rss.`building_iron`, wp_castle_rss.`building_silver`, CASE WHEN `building_food` <0 THEN `building_food`=0 END FROM wp_castle_rss

Comment: SELECT wp_castle_rss.`building_level`,
      ((wp_castle_rss.`building_food` *.2)-12000000 )AS `building_food` ,
       wp_castle_rss.`building_wood`,
       wp_castle_rss.`building_iron`,
       wp_castle_rss.`building_silver`,
CASE
    WHEN `building_food` <0  THEN `building_food`=0
END
FROM wp_castle_rss

Comment: ok put the backquotes in and the table is formed from the mysql connection.  yes the first error was the one you stated.  Now i am getting the can't caluculate the position.

Comment: Please share more details, like the error message in text form

Comment: I have the table's already built based off the simple select without trying to do math in the middle I am just rying to change what is displayed so i can make other tables based off buying a piece of gear in game.  So based numbers x 660 pieces of data then i modify the 660 pieces by 3 mulipliers and build new tables.  Sounded simple enough. I normally would do this with php but for security reasons I am avoiding that layer and not everyone of the 200,000 people coming to website has the gear the table can't be static.

Comment: As you can see for some reason the mysql that is giving error is STILL doing the math its just not taking any answer that is negative and making it a ZERO for a clean user display.